# How to install nodejs specific version

Tags: nodejs

I have installed `nodejs` using `sudo apt-get install nodejs`. This installed  version 0.10.32 but I want to install version 0.10.15. I already tried this command

`sudo apt-get install nodejs=0.10.15-1chl1~precise1`

which returned

`E: Version '0.10.15-1chl1~precise1' for 'nodejs' was not found`

I also tried `sudo apt-get install nodejs=0.10.15`

my Ubuntu version is 14.10 and I'm trying to install through the PPA.

Is there any solution guys... ?

Comment: The syntax for specifying version is `sudo apt-get install nodejs=version`, but the version has to be available. What version of Ubuntu are you on? Are you using a PPA?

Comment: I am excuting this command  sudo apt-get install nodejs=0.10.15-1chl1~precise1 and getting error E: Version '0.10.15-1chl1~precise1' for 'nodejs' was not found also tried sudo apt-get install nodejs=0.10.15

Comment: my ubuntu version is 14.10 PPA is added

Comment: 14.10 is not supported here yet. And it seems that version is not available for you via apt. Compile from source.

Comment: You have any command or guide to compile it ...!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can find the particular release you need here

```
https://nodejs.org/dist/
```

a given release dir typically lists these :

```
node-v0.10.15-darwin-x64.tar.gz                    25-Jul-2013 23:59 
node-v0.10.15-darwin-x86.tar.gz                    25-Jul-2013 23:59 
node-v0.10.15-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz                  12-Aug-2013 20:52 
node-v0.10.15-linux-x64.tar.gz                     25-Jul-2013 23:59
node-v0.10.15-sunos-x64.tar.gz                     25-Jul-2013 23:59
node-v0.10.15-sunos-x86.tar.gz                     25-Jul-2013 23:59
node-v0.10.15-x86.msi                              25-Jul-2013 23:59
node-v0.10.15.pkg                                  25-Jul-2013 23:59
node-v0.10.15.tar.gz                               25-Jul-2013 23:59
```

notice various OS specific pre-compiled versions and the source code :

```
node-v0.10.15.tar.gz
```

which mentions no OS ... pick either way (binary or source) ... either way you will need to setup environment variables

today let's compile the source code ... expand tarball :

```
tar xvf node-v0.10.15.tar.gz
cd node-v0.10.15
```

before compiling do you want to use `sudo` to install npm packages later ... or do you prefer to avoid being root and just issue commands as yourself ... if yourself then this works :

```
# export NODE_PARENT=/usr/local/bin/nodejs  # use this ONLY if you MUST install as root (sudo)
export NODE_PARENT=${HOME}/node-v5.0.0      # Recommended - owned by you NOT root
```

either way you need these two as well

```
export PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/bin:${PATH}
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/lib/node_modules
```

now once above env vars are defined and active in current shell issue

```
./configure --prefix=${NODE_PARENT}
make
make install
```

Done ... verify by issuing

```
node --version
```