# Installing Current nodejs version

Tags: nodejs, npm

Starting to learn Nodejs in Ubuntu (New to ubuntu as well). when I use `apt install nodejs` , v8.x.x is getting installe instead of current v12.x.x.
I tried to use nvm using from [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)  but it is only installing node and not nodejs.

I tried to install from nodejs.org but it's just installing a tar package and I'm not sure how to install it or even if I'm able to install, do not find any easy way to update the node version.

Can someone provide me right way to install latest nodejs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS provides instructions for installing the latest versions of Node through various package managers [on their website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions-enterprise-linux-fedora-and-snap-packages).

> For Node.js v12.x:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will the nodejs update to 13.x.x when released if I use sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade.

Comment: I would imagine not as the provided repositories are linked to their major version number.

Answer (score 0):

Use the commands below:

`sudo n list` => show the list of installed versions sudo n stable => install latest stable version.

`sudo n stable` => install latest stable version

`sudo n <version number>` (ex: sudo n 12.18.3) to install the specific version of nodejs

Additionally, you can also use nvm (especially in case of Windows os, because above commands works on Linux) to install or switch between node versions.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu now has Node.js in its default repositories that can be used to provide a consistent experience across multiple systems.
you can install it via apt:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install nodejs`

If the package in the repositories suits your needs, this is all you need to do to get set up with Node.js. In most cases, you’ll also want to also install `npm`, the Node.js package manager. You can do this by installing the `npm` package with `apt` as well:

`sudo apt install npm`

the build tools also avaiable here

`sudo apt install build tools`